# document not defined for document.querySelector

Tags: html, reactjs, jsx

I am trying to render data from my firebase backend onto my website. I have a function in ../components/Storefront.js

```
function Storefront(props) {
return (
<section>
<ul className="service-list"></ul>
</section>
}
```

In another file, ../pages/storefront.js, I'm trying to render a function to "service-list",

```
import Storefront from './../components/Storefront';
const servicelist = document.querySelector('.service-list');

function renderServices(doc){
  let li = document.createElement('li');
  let name = document.createElement('span');
  let description = document.createElement('span');

  li.setAttribute('data-id', doc.id);
  name.textContent = doc.data().name;
  description.textContent = doc.data().description;

  li.appendChild(name);
  li.appendChild(description);

  servicelist.appendChild(li);
}
```

However, I keep getting a document is not defined error pointing to my

```
const servicelist = document.querySelector('.service-list');
```

I tried doing ('#service-list') which doesn't help. Is this because querySelector doesn't work with JSX and only HTML? Any advice will be greatly appreciated!

Comment: I think your code may be running too early, before the DOM is loaded.  Try using `window.onload` to call a function after the DOM has loaded.

Comment: Should I add that inside my function Storefront at the beginning? Or separately in the pages/storefront.js?

Comment: I added an answer as it's hard to write code in comments.

Answer (score 0):

I believe the issue is that your `const servicelist = document.querySelector...` line is at file scope which means it runs **immediately** when the file is loaded, and that's too early because the DOM has not loaded.  Try changing the first part of the code like this.

```
import Storefront from './../components/Storefront';
let servicelist;

function init() {
    console.log("Initializing");
    servicelist = document.querySelector('.service-list');
    // anything else you want to do on initialize
}

window.onload = init;

// The rest as you have it already.
```

Here's a good intro: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/GlobalEventHandlers/onload

Comment: I get a 'window is not defined' error when trying to use window.onload. Any idea why?

Comment: Oh!  I think I misinterpreted your situation.  This code will only work in the browser, not on the server.  JSX and `document` and `window` are purely browser-side constructs.  I'm afraid there isn't an easy patch to make.  You should read about making a JSX webapp (https://reactjs.org/docs/introducing-jsx.html), and having it talk to your server to get data.  Or alternatively, make your server emit plain HTML and JS for the browser, but don't try to make the server actually *invoke* the JS itself.